# Checking innerHTML value in javascript code doesn't work with icon

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to check with this code to see what the innerHTML value of a HTML element is. It works with "Check." but as soon as I change it to the following it doesn't work anymore.

```
function namelength() {
  name = document.getElementById("name");
  check = document.getElementById("namecheck");
  if (name.value.length > 3) {
    check.innerHTML = "Check."; -----> check.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>"
    name.style.border = "2px solid green";
    namecheck.style.color = "green";
  }

}

function checkform() {
  check = document.getElementById("namecheck").innerHTML;
    if (check == "Check.") -----> if (check = "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>") {
      ...
    }
```

So again "Check." works but as soon as I use the i class (to show an icon from the font awesome library) itt doesn't. It shows the icon properly it's just the check in checkform() that doesn't recognize the icon.

Comment: What element is `#name`? Note, that only form control elments have value. Also, `name` is not a good name for a global variable, nor id. It's a property in the window object.

Comment: Use `==` or better yet `===` instead of `=`?

Comment: Where is the `namecheck` variable defined? I see you have defined `name` as one variable and `check` as another but I don't see `namecheck`. Shouldn't it be `check.innerHTML = "Check.";`

Comment: I'm sorry I made some mistakes when translating the variable names from my language to english. Those are not the problem though, it literally works with "Check." but doesn't with "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>".

Comment: That's because the innerHTML doesn't match "Check." if it's = to `<i class='fa fa-check'></i>`

Comment: I tried changing if (check == "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>") to (check = "<i class='fa fa-check'></i>") and it worked! thanks everyone.

Comment: Why not target the `<i>` within your `namecheck` element? `document.getElementById("namecheck").getElementsByTagName('i')[0].class` or just check for `document.getElementById("namecheck").getElementsByClassName('fa-check')[0]`

Comment: Here is an example- https://jsfiddle.net/u7prnecL/